# Get the data read order after feeding into an HashSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist, hashset

I get data from the `MySQL` database where it contain names of products. I have two databases. One which contains Local Products while other database carry foreign products. I need to get data from both the databases.

In order to success I use the `JDBC` connection and retreive data and put into two `arraylists`. As I want to ignore duplicates I use a `hashset`. I fed in those `arraylist` to `hashset` and then get back the `arraylist` again which do not contains duplicates.

I know that `HashSet` has no sorting way so it changes over the time. I do not want that to happen. I want to keep that read in data order as it is after removing duplicates also.

Sample Code I use:

```
    localProductHashSet.addAll(getLocalProduct);
    getLocalProduct.clear();
    getLocalProduct.addAll(localProductHashSet);
    Collections.sort(getLocalProduct);
```

Comment: Yeah ok my bad, noted in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) like [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) if you want to use a `Comparator` or implement `Comparable<T>` on your data models to keep them in some specified order.

Otherwise, try a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which will keep your objects in the order they were inserted.